# "npx react-native run-ios" is picking non existing simulator

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

As per https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup, I'm trying to run sample project on iOS simulator

When I ran command `npx react-native run-ios` getting error

```
info Found Xcode workspace "AwesomeProject.xcworkspace"
error No simulator available with name "iPhone 12".
```

From where does it picking `iPhone 12`, I don't have that simulator in first place

Answer (score 48):

Open Xcode and check which simulators are installed or list available simulators in terminal with `xcrun simctl list devices`.

Then define a simulator you wanna use:

```
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 13"
```

Comment: I know this step but it didn't answer from where does it pick up "iPhone12" , that simulator is not even present

Comment: Your projects xcode file and check which simulator is selected

Comment: The argument is with a double dash `--simulator='iPhone 13'`. At least thats what worked for me.

Comment: how do you get the iphone 13 sim?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper Install the simulator with Xcode first.

Comment: for anyone who wants to know the name of an installed simulator, open xcode > window (at the top) > Devices and simulators.  if you can't find it , click on "Help" (at the top) and type in the search input "simulator" , it will show you it's location , click on the place where the arrow is pointing and you will see the list of simulators

Answer (score 14):

If you're coming from React Native, follow these:

1. Accept XCode licence aggreement:

> ```
> sudo xcodebuild -license
> ```

2. Run simulator using iPhone 14, if you haven't added old iPhones:

> ```
> npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 14"
> ```

3. Make sure you have chosen command line tools on XCode:

> `Xcode => Preferences => Locations`

[image: Location Tab]

Answer (score 8):

React Native will pick a particular device by default, depending on its version.
As of version `0.67.2`, for example, it'll try to boot an [iPhone 13 by default](https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-simulator-ios) regardless of it existing locally or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and I fixed it by creating a new simulator with this exact name (case sensitive)
Open Simulator App > File > New Simulator > create one with the name from the error

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. Then i just run

```
sudo npx expo start
```

Resolve the incompatible dependencies it will show you.

Press " i " to run the app. The app will open on a booted simulator.

See available with :

```
xcrun simctl list devices
```

Comment: OP did not specify if they're using expo.